# Microsoft Graph drive orderby last modified date

Tags: json, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to do 2 things with my query: it should get all files within the drive and it should order them by lastModifiedDateTime. My console.log shows the following:

```
Array[3]
0:Object
1:Object
2:Object
@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl:
"https://one365dev1.sharepoint.com/sites/Group100/_layouts/15/download.aspx?guestaccesstoken=H8k8YdpvSbJ5Os7N5wMeKsWTPlTVudH1lMXw5LH7Bfo%3d&docid=0704e91431c934ae6a0ae721311f5ac4a&expiration=2016-11-14T16%3a25%3a02.000Z&userid=3&authurl=True&NeverAuth=True"
cTag:""c:{704E9143-1C93-4AE6-A0AE-721311F5AC4A},5""
createdBy:Object
createdDateTime:"2016-11-14T15:04:48Z"
eTag:""{704E9143-1C93-4AE6-A0AE-721311F5AC4A},6""
file:Object
id:"01SGMLUFSDSFHHBEY44ZFKBLTSCMI7LLCK"
lastModifiedBy:Object
lastModifiedDateTime:"2016-11-14T15:06:10Z"
name:"test excel.xlsx"
parentReference:Object
size:12921
webUrl:"https://one365dev1.sharepoint.com/sites/Group100/_layouts/15/WopiFrame.aspx?sourcedoc=%7B704E9143-1C93-4AE6-A0AE-721311F5AC4A%7D&file=test%20excel.xlsx&action=default"
```

However when I use:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/eab89ea3-fc94-4eb9-8f47-f6d2b0a7ea88/drive/root/children?orderby=lastModifiedDateTime

it returns nothing. If I remove the $orderby, it returns it as usual.

Answer (score 1):

This link : https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/eab89ea3-fc94-4eb9-8f47-f6d2b0a7ea88/drive/root/children?orderby=lastModifiedDateTime

returns this output :

```json
{
  "error": {
    "code": "InvalidAuthenticationToken",
    "message": "Bearer access token is empty.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "0c7100fe-bf7d-45e6-bb4b-a68d29d5a41f",
      "date": "2018-03-07T11:36:50"
    }
  }
}
```

is this expected?

Answer (score 0):

The operation appears not to be supported. This is the response I get when making a similar request:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "notSupported",
        "message": "The property Modified is not supported for OrderBy.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2022-08-23T12:52:45",
            "request-id": "<guid>",
            "client-request-id": "<guid>"
        }
    }
}
```